# stop ForEach loop from running code 5 times per item

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach

I would like my code to insert 1 document per every item in the loop, however it keeps inserting 5 of each one. I've been at this for hours and it's 3:41am, please help.

The code is cluttered so simply put, the loop will scan a list of categories and use the index of that category to extract other data that goes with it like how many points the person made in that category, on what day, etc.

I am using nodejs and what you will see below is a method on one of my Schema's that I called in my router.js file.

Yes, I have read over 15 question here I thought might help but not in the coding language I'm using and not with the exact issue.

The for loop build the point object which I'm trying to save in the student's profile.

```
    //the for loop should build something like this
            { date: '9/13/2017',
              category:"Participation",
              specification:"Pitchball Game",
              points:150
            }
```

Js file:

```
    StudentSchema.statics.givePoints = function (pt_obj, cb){
var leng =pt_obj.category.length;
var i=0;
var rsc = 'r' + pt_obj.room + '-' + pt_obj.seat;
Student.findOne( {rscombo: rsc },  function (err, student){
    if ( err || !student){
        console.log('not a student');
    }
    else{

        pt_obj.category.forEach(function( cat, ind){

            if(cat != '' && cat != null && cat != undefined && cat != '--select--'){
                var pts = Number(pt_obj.pts[ind]);

                student.points.push({ date: pt_obj.date[ind], category: cat, specification : pt_obj.specification[ind], points:Number(pt_obj.pts[ind]), sysdate:pt_obj.date[ind] });

                if(cat != 'Purchase'){


                    ptMonth = Number(pt_obj.date[ind].slice( 0, pt_obj.date[ind].indexOf('/') ) );

                    var query ={starlight:pts, balance:pts};
                    var trailMe  = 'lightTrails' + ptMonth + '.';
                    var trailCat;
                    var hightrail= trailMe + '0';
                    query[hightrail]=pts;


                    switch (cat){
                        case 'Behavior':
                            trailCat= trailMe + '1';
                            query[trailCat]=pts;
                            console.log(trailCat);
                            break;
                        case 'Contest':
                            trailCat= trailMe + '2';
                            query[trailCat]=pts;
                            console.log(trailCat);
                            break;
                        case 'Game':
                            trailCat= trailMe + '3';
                            query[trailCat]=pts;
                            console.log(trailCat);
                            break;
                        case 'High Score':
                            trailCat= trailMe + '4';
                            query[trailCat]=pts;
                            console.log(trailCat);
                            break;
                        case 'Participation':
                            trailCat= trailMe + '5';
                            query[trailCat]=pts;
                            console.log(trailCat);
                            break;
                        case 'Wage':
                            trailCat= trailMe + '6';
                            query[trailCat]=pts;
                            console.log(trailCat);
                            break;
                    }


                    console.log('attacking query \n' + query);


                    //always add it to the starlight, highlight as well as specific category
                    Student.update( { rscombo : rsc } , { $inc: query }, function (err, student){
                        if(err || !student){
                            console.log('update unsuccessful');
                        } });
                } else{
                    var pts = Number(pt_obj.pts[ind]);
                    Student.update( { rscombo : rsc } , { $inc: { balance: pts} }, function (err){
                        if(err){
                            console.log('update unsuccessful');
                        }
                    } );
                }
            }
            if( leng-1 == i){
                student.save(cb);
            }else{
                student.save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            }
            i++;
        });
    }
});
return Student.findOne( { rscombo: 'r' + pt_obj.room + '-' + pt_obj.seat},  cb);
```

}

Comment: Hi..As far I can understand reading your code, do you wanna save a student for each category?

Comment: no I want to save the point information into the student's point table. In order to do that I need the for each loop to build the point object. I will edit post to show what i mean.

Comment: so what line is the problem ?

Comment: right where you see the for each loop. It keeps putting the same point-data in 5 times. There is a line where I push the data into the database and that's where I think I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to build the point object in the loop, but push it after the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amor, what you said got me to thinking and I switch my code so that my forEach is on the outside and the findOne method is in the inside. It seems to have worked. Thank you so much.

```
  pt_obj.category.forEach(cat, ind){ 
    Student.findOne({}, function (){

    })
  }
```